# HTML Canvas: Rotate the Image 3D effect

Tags: html, canvas

How can i rotate the image (eg. to 45degrees) and squash the image. supposed i have a perfect square image. I can rotate it to any angle i want but i want to make the rotated square squashed, making the height 2/3 smaller than the width. the resulting image would be not a perfect rotated square but a squashed one.

do you know how can I achieve the effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squishing a square is exceedingly easy, simply apply a scale:

`ctx.scale(1, 2/3); // squish it to 2/3 vertical size`

You'll have to translate it by the `(opposite fraction * the height) / 2` to get it centered, though.

So to rotate and then squish a 200x200 square image you'd simply:

```
// rotation first
ctx.translate(100,100);
ctx.rotate(.3);
ctx.translate(-100,-100);

// than scale
ctx.translate(0,200 * (1/3) / 2) // move by half of the 1/3 space to center it
ctx.scale(1, 2/3); // squish it to 2/3 vertical size

ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/3Qr3S/

Comment: +1 for giving the OP exactly what he asked for, but I think he is actually looking to use 2D distortion to “fake” 3D.  If I misunderstand, please forgive me for stepping on toes.  BTW,  I lived in Peterborough,NH for 3 years—nice area!

Comment: hi thanks for your code. can you show me a sample of a cat that is rotated to 90 or 45 degrees but the height(top to bottom) is 1/3 smaller than the width (left to right) with respect to the flat surface/horizon? (i hope im asking the question right)

Answer (score 2):

**You can use 2D canvas to “fake” 3d by distorting width vs height**

Do this by using context.drawImage and varying the width vs the height disproportionally

```
// draw image increasingly "squashed"
// to fake a 3d effect
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,
    left,
    10,
    (300-(right-left))/1,
    300-(right-left)/1.5);
```

You can play with the distortion ratios to get different effects, but it’s all just “squishing”.

Here’s code and a Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/J2WfS/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();

        var left=1.0;
        var right=300;
        var sizing=.25;

        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
          animate();
        }
        img.src="koolaidman.png";

        function animate() {

          // update scaling factors
          left+=sizing;
          right-=sizing;
          if(left<0 || left>100){sizing = -sizing;}
          console.log(left+"/"+right);


          // clear and save the context
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          ctx.save();

          // draw image increasingly "squashed"
          // to fake a 3d effect
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,
              left,
              10,
              (300-(right-left))/1,
              300-(right-left)/1.5);

          ctx.restore();

          // request new frame
          requestAnimFrame(function() {
            animate();
          });
        }
        animate();

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=235></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the codes and the help. what i want is, i want an image to be rotated... like 0 up to 360 degrees... but i want to to be squashed perfectly slightly smaller from top to bottom.