# How can I create a perspective effect within a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, css-transforms

I know how to create a perspective effect in vanilla CSS, but how can I create this effect in a canvas?

```css
.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 40px;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  /* perspective function in transform property */
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

I tried the [`setTransform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) method without sucess.

```js
function drawScene(margin, size) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(margin, margin, size, size);
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var margin = 100;
var size = 200;

drawScene(margin, size)

ctx.setTransform(1, -0.1, 0, 1, -10, 0);
//ctx.rotate(1 * Math.PI / 180); how to rotateY

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(margin, margin, size, size);

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.font = "48px Courier";
ctx.fillText("hello", margin, size);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

I tried both solution from [HTML Canvas: Rotate the Image 3D effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050771/html-canvas-rotate-the-image-3d-effect) but none nailed it. The perspective effet isnt here.

Comment: The 2D API as the name suggest only does 2D, perspective is 3D. It can be done in 2D but you will need to do all the math and all the rendering (very slow). For 3D on the canvas (including perspective) use webGL

Comment: @Blindman67 do you have an example with webgl?

Comment: Have you looked into threejs? I imagine this example is something simple, but you are ultimately looking to build something more complex, stuff like: https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/three.js/dev/examples/webgl_shadowmap2.html

Answer (score -1):

You need create a path by points matrix (x1, y1; x2, y2; x3, y3; x4, y4). Apply a transform matrix in your point matrix. After, print on canvas with path.

1: You need study by tranformation matrix (http://docdingle.com/teaching/cs545/presents/p12b_cs545_WarpsP2.pdf)

2:In Summary you have a transformation' matrix to translading, space, rotate or apply perspective deformation:

```js
    //this is a tranformation matrix to percpective deformation A and B are values that apply deformation
    matrix_tranf = [ [1, 0 ,0] ,  [0,1,0] , [ A, B, 1] ];
```

In my code I left any examples

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    //u
    x1 = matrix[i][0]
    //v
    y1 = matrix[i][1]
    w = matrix_tranf[2][0] * x1 + matrix_tranf[2][1] * y1 + 1;
    v = [  ( x1 / w ) , ( y1 / w )  ];
    matrix[i] = v;
}
```

Look
https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/pen/wvoqEwg

If this answer help you, check as correct or voteup!

Comment: Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: look my ansewr again @aloisdg! If this answer help you, check as correct or voteup!

Comment: You are drawing a rect as it it were under a perspective. Will it work with any content? Let say an image or a text? Not gonna lie. Warps are cool. I am not sure we can apply this kind of transformation to a `fillText()`. I may be wrong though.

Comment: No, only elements with Paths. Maybe this lib solve you problem: https://github.com/evanw/glfx.js.

Look demo in http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/demo/#perspective

```javascript
 
canvas.draw(texture).perspective([175,156,496,55,161,279,504,330], [175,156,496,55.00000000000001,161,279,504,330]).update();
```

Comment: but, you need study on transformation.You can use this knowledge to transform forms as rect and imagens. I think that you can use 2 canvas, in second you apply transformation in data image. After, print this in first canvas. This is only a ideia!